# Recursively Generate Every Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I am working on a project where I generate every possible tic-tac-toe array. As a proof of concept, I am working on code to fill an array with 9 subarrays. Each subarray will have two values, the first one being 0 or 1 (for x and o respectively), and the second one being from 1 to 9 (representing when it was placed).
An example of an array I would like to get out would look like:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [0, 4], [1, 5], [0, 6], [1, 7], [0, 8]]
```

I have already written code, using 9 for loops, each one nested in the one above, which gives me the desired results (every possible array, and each one unique). But I am trying to write code, using recursion, and avoiding writing tons of nested loops.

When I run the code below, it is only able to generate the array above, and cannot create other combinations. My code is below:

```
print("running...")

allGames = []
checkCurrentGame = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
stepsDown = 0

def cleanGame(move, currentGame):
    for j in range(9):
        if (currentGame[j][1] >= move):
            currentGame[j] = [5, 0]

def completeMove(moveNumber, currentGame):
    global stepsDown
    stepsDown = stepsDown + 1
    for i in range(9):
        cleanGame(moveNumber, currentGame)
        if (currentGame[i][0] == 5):
            currentGame[i][0] = i % 2
            currentGame[i][1] = moveNumber
            allGames.append(currentGame)
            break
    if (stepsDown < 9):
        generateGame(currentGame)

def generateGame(currentGame):
    for i in range(9):
        completeMove(i, currentGame)

generateGame([[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]])

for x in range(len(allGames)):
    print(allGames[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly this should do, however this is not recursion -

```
import itertools
[zip(p, range(0, 9)) for p in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=9)]
```

The code first generates a board (9 0's or 1's) -

```
itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=9)
```

and then add the index data to it.

I recommend having a look in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Comment: This is not good, since it contains many invalid entries. For example the very first entry is `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]`.

Comment: Also, it only includes games in wich the cells are filled sequentially. So it misses a lot of valid games in which e.g. the first player start in the middle.

Comment: It contains all possible entries - len([zip(p, range(0, 9)) for p in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=9)]) = 512=2^9.

Comment: But 512 is not all the possible entries. You need to take into account which cell was filled first, second, ... last. That means a factor of 9!. Here is a representation of a valid game: `[(0,8), (1,7), (0,6), (1,5), (0,4), (1,3), (0,2), (1,0), (0,0)]` (note that 0 and 1 alternating in filling cells). Can you find it in your list of 512? It's not there... Furthermore you did not address the fact that your code will yield incorrect entries.

Comment: It looks like you may have misunderstood the question. 2^9 will give us all combinations of 9 zeros and ones. Tic-tac-toe games are a significantly smaller subset of that and the OP's game representation also includes a number in each cell's data for "when it [the move] was placed."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auK3PSZoidc) on youtube. The professor teaches really nicely about recursion. I think it will benefit for you more, then getting a working code. He uses sudoku as an example, but both games are just 2D arrays.

If you watched the video, you will know how to modify this example to better suit your needs.
A pseudo code:

```
def place(who, when, where, table):
    if (None, None) not in table: # the table is full
        print(table)
        return

    if table[where] not (None, None): # this cell is already marked
        return

    table[where] (who, when) # can place our mark on the cell
    # make the recursive calls
    for i in range(9):
        place(who.opponent, when+1, i, table)

for cell in range(9):
    empty = [(None, None) for _ in range(9)]
    place(firstplayer, 0, cell, empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fun. Here's a method that plays the game, branching off each possible move (or at any rate, that's the intention).

Although my preference is usually to concat and return a pure result, to allow for an early exit and inspection, this recursion accumulates in a global variable.

```py
import copy
import json
import time

s = set()
rs = []

def f():
  """
  111
  111000
  111000000
  1001001
  10010010
  100100100
  1010100
  100010001
  """
  wins = [0007,0070,0700,0111,0222,0444,0124,0421]
  def winner(board):
    # check xs or os individual board for a win
    for i in wins:
      if not (i ^ (board & i)):
        return True
    return False

  # xs board, os board, move-number, game
  def g(xs, os, move, result):
    # allow for early exit
    global rs
    if (len(rs) > 20000):
      return

    # base case, win or draw
    if winner(xs) or winner(os) or move == 9:
      #print "{0:b}".format(xs)
      #print "{0:b}".format(os)
      #print (result, xs, os)
      #print

      # confirm we're not duplicating results
      enc = json.dumps(result)
      if enc in s:
        print "Duplicate!"
        print result
      s.add(enc)

      # accumulate results
      rs.append((result, xs, os))
      return

    board = xs | os

    for i in xrange(9):
      # candidate move
      m = 1 << i

      # valid move
      if not (m & board):
        _result = copy.deepcopy(result)

        # 'O' plays on odd numbered moves
        if move & 1:
          _result[i] = [1, move]
          g(xs, os | m, move + 1, _result)

        # 'X' plays on even numbered moves
        else:
          _result[i] = [0, move]
          g(xs | m, os, move + 1, _result)

  # start the recursion
  g(0, 0, 0, [[-1, -1]] * 9)

start_time = time.time()
f()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```py
"""
rs[2002]

=> ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [-1, -1],
   [-1, -1], [1, 5], [0, 2],
     [0, 4], [1, 3], [-1, -1]], 97, 146)

x--
---
---

xo-
---
---

xo-
--x
---

xo-
--x
-o-

xo-
--x
xo-

xo-
-ox
xo-
"""
```